# JSF: How to add ajax functionality to component in backing bean?

Tags: java, ajax, jsf, jsf-2

I want to incorporate the  functionality to a HtmlCommandButton.  How do I go about doing that?  I can't seem to find too many examples on the web.  I see there is something called AjaxBehavoir, but I'm not sure how to incorporate that into my HtmlCommandButton.  Essentially I want to do the following to my component:

```
  <f:ajax execute="@this" render="component1 component2" />
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should familiarize yourself with the components of the new `javax.faces.component.behavior` package in the [JSF 2.0](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17802_01/j2ee/javaee/javaserverfaces/2.0/docs/api/index.html) API.

I don't know if it is recommended to use a programmatic approach to set up ajax behavior directly in your backing bean instead of the more common idiom:

```
<h:commandButton>
 <f:ajax event="onclick" execute="@this" render="component1 component2" />
</h:commandButton>
```

Here are a couple of links that should get you up and running with this.

- [JSF 2.0 jsf.ajax JavaScript API](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17802_01/j2ee/javaee/javaserverfaces/2.0/docs/js-api/symbols/jsf.ajax.html#constructor)
- [JSF 2.0 Client Behavior](http://java.dzone.com/articles/jsf-2-client-behaviors) (Very good introduction as to how the Ajax behavior defined in your `<f:ajax>` components is mapped to and from a backing bean).

Hope this can help.

Regards.

Comment: Thanks for the links...I tried using the "setOnclick" method as suggested in one of the links, but still isn't working.  I'll keey trying.

Comment: If you think it's going to be verbose to have the f:ajax inside every command button, you can wrap this into a composite component and us it like this...

<steve:ajaxCommandButton value="Click me!" action="#{somebean.someaction}" render="component1 component2"/>